# Adding namespace definition to xml using apache xmlbeans

Tags: java, xml, xmlbeans

I need to add namespace defintion to an element since its not getting added when when xml is generated using apache xmlbean. How do I acheieve this using xmlbeans API?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have found answer to the problem.
Here's how it is.

```
XmlCursor cursor= targetObject.newCursor();
cursor.toNextToken();
cursor.insertNamespace("A", "namespace1");
//For example
cursor.insertNamespace("xsi", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");
cursor.dispose();
```

Comment: I had to call cursor.toNextToken() twice, otherwise this was what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
XmlOptions.setSaveSuggestedPrefixes()

XmlOptions xmlOptions = new XmlOptions();

xmlOptions.setSavePrettyPrint();

xmlOptions.setSavePrettyPrintIndent(4);

xmlOptions.setSaveAggressiveNamespaces();

HashMap<String, String> nsMap = new HashMap<String, String>();

nsMap.put("namespace1","A");

nsMap.put("http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance", "xsi");

xmlOptions.setSaveSuggestedPrefixes(nsMap);

// Create your XmlObject

<Your XmlObject>.save(new File("test.xml"),xmlOptions);
```

Comment: Didn't work for me - this only sets the suggested prefixes. As far as I understand, the original question was about adding a namespace definition to documents that don't actually use that namespace.