# Add prefix to all tags xml of a Dom Element

Tags: java, xml, dom, xmlbeans

Now am extracting xml blocs from a large xml file.
So for each bloc i want to adjust it to have the same prefix and name space like the original file.
the type of actual bloc xml is Element.

The Actual bloc :

```
    <xml-fragment>
  <Derived_Event_Code>xxx</Derived_Event_Code>
  <Effective_Moment>2018-10-25T07:29:12</Effective_Moment>
  <Entry_Moment>2018-10-25T07:29:12</Entry_Moment>
  <Related_Person isUpdated="1">
    <Legal_Name>
      <First_Name>xxxx</First_Name>
      <Last_Name>xxxx</Last_Name>
    </Legal_Name>
  </Related_Person>
</xml-fragment>
```

desired result:

```
<xml-fragment xmlns:peci="urn:com.uri/peci">
  <peci:Derived_Event_Code>DTA</peci:Derived_Event_Code>
  <peci:Effective_Moment>2018-10-25T07:29:12</peci:Effective_Moment>
  <peci:Entry_Moment>2018-10-25T07:29:12</peci:Entry_Moment>
  <peci:Related_Person isUpdated="1">
    <peci:Legal_Name>
      <peci:First_Name>xxxx</peci:First_Name>
      <peci:Last_Name>xxxx</peci:Last_Name>
    </peci:Legal_Name>
  </peci:Related_Person>
</xml-fragment>
```

I tried this code :

```
Element originalDocumentElement = eltF;     
                    Element NewElement=eltF.getOwnerDocument().createElementNS(namespace, eltF.getNodeName());
                    NewElement.setPrefix("peci");

                    NodeList list = eltF.getChildNodes();
                    int j=1;
                    while(list.getLength()!=0) {
                        Node Exp =list.item(0);
                        System.out.println(Exp.getNodeName());
                        System.out.println(eltF.getNodeName());
                        Element NewSubElmnt=list.item(0).getOwnerDocument().createElementNS(namespace, list.item(0).getNodeName());
                        NewSubElmnt.setNodeValue(list.item(0).getNodeValue().toString());
                        NewSubElmnt.setPrefix("peci");


                        NewElement.appendChild(list.item(0));


                    }
```

The erros was:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BI5Oi.jpg)

and he is right to raise this error because when i debeug i found that `list.item(0).getNodeValue()` contain "#text" and doesn't contain the name of node.

however when i make in comment the bloc of creation of new child elements :

```
                        Element NewElement=eltF.getOwnerDocument().createElementNS(namespace, eltF.getNodeName());
                        NewElement.setPrefix("peci");

                        NodeList list = eltF.getChildNodes();
                        int j=1;
                        while(list.getLength()!=0) {
//                          Node Exp =list.item(0);
//                          System.out.println(Exp.getNodeName());
//                          System.out.println(eltF.getNodeName());
//                          Element NewSubElmnt=list.item(0).getOwnerDocument().createElementNS(namespace, list.item(0).getNodeName());
//                          NewSubElmnt.setNodeValue(list.item(0).getNodeValue().toString());
//                          NewSubElmnt.setPrefix("peci");


                            NewElement.appendChild(list.item(0));


                        }

                        /*********/

                        /*********/
                        factory=XmlObject.Factory.parse(NewElement);        
                         System.out.println(factory.toString());
```

In the console i get all the new bloc as i want but the prefix is assigned just to the first parent node

```
<peci:xml-fragment xmlns:peci="urn:com.uri/peci">
  <Derived_Event_Code>xxx</Derived_Event_Code>
  <Effective_Moment>2018-10-25T07:29:12</Effective_Moment>
  <Entry_Moment>2018-10-25T07:29:12</Entry_Moment>
  <Related_Person isUpdated="1">
    <Legal_Name>
      <First_Name>xxxx</First_Name>
      <Last_Name>xxxxx</Last_Name>
    </Legal_Name>
  </Related_Person>
</peci:xml-fragment>
```

or i want the prefix for all tags.

How can i make it.

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: Have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2995079/adding-namespace-definition-to-xml-using-apache-xmlbeans

Comment: Thank you Eugen, i tried it but it doesn't work for me.

Comment: i tired to set prefix when i create the new element with namespace.the name sapce was aded but i didn't go the prefix for each attribute. the code is :`      Element NewElement=eltF.getOwnerDocument().createElementNS(namespace, eltF.getNodeName());
      NewElement.setPrefix("peci");`

Comment: Shouldn't the last line be `NewElement.appendChild(NewSubElmnt);` ? Other than that, explain what error you get.

Comment: i modified the question with all what i tried